# How to simulate GPS signals in my lab?

Tags: gps

I work with a lot of field equipment in a university lab; much of this equipment requires GPS signal to work properly. Unfortunately, we have zero GPS reception in the lab where we do all the testing. I'm looking for a way to produce a valid (not necessarily accurate) GPS signal in our lab.

I've seen that GPS repeaters are available, but I think it would be an ordeal to install an antenna on the outside of the building and run a cable through the wall to our lab. (It's a university building and they would have to approve this and make it happen...probably not worth the effort/money.)

I was thinking that it should always be possible to simulate a GPS signal for a known location and broadcast it. Does anyone know of any "GPS simulators" that calculate what the GPS signals should be at our lab (or anywhere, really) and broadcasts it in the room?

Or, does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: NMEA protocol is pretty simple. Just write a simple program generating the desired data stream from the serial port.

Comment: It's apparently possible to simulate it with SDR: https://hackaday.com/2016/07/19/pokemon-go-cheat-fools-gps-with-software-defined-radio/

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to have exact GPS like testing, you can do for this: http://www.labsat.co.uk/index.php/en/products/labsat-3

On the other hand, your intention is just to test the data stream, create a dummy one and play it over the port through another uC.

Comment: "Prices will start at $4,400. For further details, visit the LabSat website." Bound to work!

Comment: @winny, bound to work, I agree. Unless it's MIT or Caltech, no one would sponsor! But the device is pretty good.

Comment: There are other vendors of GPS simulators, with a range of products from simulating a single satellite, to simulating all the common constellations, GPS, GLONASS and Galileo.

Comment: Have a look to kickstarter. I remembder there were SDR boards: Hack RF, Blade RF, and many others. Check if someaone already emulated GPS signal with them. https://github.com/osqzss/gps-sdr-sim